# Read out PCs with a specific policy in AD with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was wondering if it was possible to get a list of PC names witch all have the Policy 'example' in PowerShell and write them into an array?

This is the Policy and I would like to read out the PCs marked read into an array.

[image]

Comment: Which policy and how is it applied? By OU, by security group, individually somehow?

Comment: @AthomSfere The Policy is one that tells all PCs with SSDs that Networkboot to wait for the network because the SSDs boot to fast. The PCs are manualy added to the policy.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to check the locally cached policies, and not so much Active Directory?

Comment: Sounds good. In the end i'll be adding more computers to the policy any way (per PowerShell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sort of messy way to just see if the local policy has applied the policy.

```
$result = gpresult /r
$result -match "security Policy Name"
$?
```

If the machine that runs this has the policy applied, then it will write *true* to the console, otherwise false is echoed out.

Although, my personal preference would be to build a group for the policy, and then report against the membersOf that group.